# Conditions Where update select in one table

Tags: sql-server

I have table after:

```
Create Table tblTest( col1 varchar(50), col2 varchar(50))
```

I have sql statement update after

```
update A set col1=col2 from tblTest A
         where col2 not like '*%' and LEN(COALESCE(col1 ,''))=0
```

Is the Conditions "Where" of Update or Select?

Comment: You should never (whitout very good knowledge) use an update without a where. There are many times reasons to do selects without where. But both Select and Update uses WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your select determines what will be updated the answer would be BOTH.